# Should be a simple 301 redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, http-status-code-301

What I think should be simple is just not working.

I have switched domains

Old URL example:
digital.photorecommendations.com/recs/2015/01/big-zoom-field-review/

New URL example: 
photorec.tv/2015/01/big-zoom-field-review/

Really just switching domain and dropping the recs folder from the URL

Using http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ to test and the outputs the correct URL

```html
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /recs
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.digital.photorecommendations\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^recs(.*) http://photorec.tv/$1 [L,R=301]
```

When I place this in the htaccess file I get 404 errors on all the pages except the home page. The htaccess file is inside the /recs folder. I have also tried it in the root directory of digital.photorecommendations.com and I get no results at all.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: I have tried it without the REwriteBase /recs too, no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have wrongly used negation in `RewriteCond` and regex also needs a fix. Use this rule in `/recs/.htaccess`:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?digital\.photorecommendations\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(index\.php)?$ http://photorec.tv/ [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?digital\.photorecommendations\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ http://photorec.tv/recs/$1 [L,R=301,NC,NE]
```

Comment: Thanks - tried it in root and no effect. Tried it in /recs/ folder and the home page there continues to work but all sub pages are broken 404 errors.

Comment: AWESOME- that works on all sub pages, on the home page though you end up at photorec.tv/recs and I need that /recs to drop.

Comment: It does not :( But I appreciate your help. I sent you a note on twitter. Let me know if you are interested.

Comment: nope- still nothing. I appreciate your reply and community-mindedness.

Comment: OH I am very sorry. because of the r=301 at some point the broken redirect was stuck in my browser and I thought this wasn't working even though it was. Thank you for your help everything is perfect.